# simple image uploader

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote a simple image uploader in C#. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Snappx
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GlobalHook.HookManager.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(MyKeyUp);
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            new Task(this.Hide).Start();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }

        string ORIGINIM;
        async void MyKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PrintScreen)
            {
                await GetImage();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else e.Handled = false;
        }

        String img = @"temp";
        async Task GetImage()
        {
            Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                }
                bitmap.Save(img, ImageFormat.Png);
            }

            using (var w = new WebClient())
            {
                var values = new NameValueCollection { { "key", "85684005b7d4faa4c33ee480010d4982" }, { "image", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(img)) } };

                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3, "Uploading", "Uploading image to Imgur", ToolTipIcon.Info);

                w.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_UploadProgressChanged);
                Task<byte[]> x = w.UploadValuesTaskAsync(new Uri("http://imgur.com/api/upload.xml"), values);
                byte[] response = await x;

                while (w.IsBusy) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                File.Delete(img);

                ORIGINIM = Convert.ToString(XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(response)));
                ORIGINIM = ORIGINIM.Substring(ORIGINIM.LastIndexOf("<original_image>")).Replace("<original_image>", "");
                ORIGINIM = ORIGINIM.Substring(0, ORIGINIM.LastIndexOf("</original_image>")).Replace("</original_image>", "");

                Clipboard.SetText(ORIGINIM);
                if (!File.Exists(@"Uploads.txt")) File.Create(@"Uploads.txt");
                new StreamWriter(@"Uploads.txt").WriteLine(ORIGINIM);
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3, "Done", "URL copied to clipboard.", ToolTipIcon.Info);
            }
        }

        private void wc_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int percentage = e.ProgressPercentage * 2;
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3, "Uploading", (percentage).ToString() + "%", ToolTipIcon.Info);
        }
    }
}
```

First of all, when there is no Uploads.txt file, it returns an Exception handler. Then second time I run it, it creates it. Is there any simpler way to store it?

**Second question:**

Am I able to add two different options, one for capture full screen and one for select screen region.

How could I integrate it with my code? Could you post it?

Comment: When you say returns Exception handler, do you mean throw an exception ?  Because according to your code it should create the file on the first run.

Comment: @igelineau Yeah, throws an exception. If there is anyway of storing it temporarily or something..

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @mrtig http://4.imgland.net/rt1n7B.png

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `(!File.Exists(@"Uploads.txt")) File.Create(@"Uploads.txt")` try this

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(@"Uploads.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
{
    sw.WriteLine(ORIGINIM);
}
```

The reason why it worked on the second try is because you didn't create a lock on the file with `File.Create` - the existing logic opens the file, which creates a `FileStream`, then you attempt to open `StreamWriter` on the same file. You should instead create the `StreamWriter` by passing the `FileStream` into its constructor, as shown in the above example.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But is there anyway to not store anything in that file? I've created that just for the test, for the public use I don't want it to be created. Does it need to be stored? If not, how could I remove it? I'm really new to all of this..

Comment: It looks like the file part doesn't really have anything to do with the upload. Try it with the file part commented out.

Comment: You can shorten the code by using `File.WriteAllText("Uploads.txt", ORIGINIM);`